# change boot order

Tags: shell, centos, partition, grub, fdisk

I have 2 partitions `sda1` XP and `sda2` CENTOS. I have reinstalled `grub` on `/dev/sda` but on rebooting, I experienced: `error : 22 no such parition` for Centos; while Windows boots charmingly on the other.

`fdisk -l` gives `sda1` as boot, is there a possibility that I can change it to `sda2` on `shell`, since I am on rescue mode.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a possibility that I can change it to sda2

fdisk utility itself has an option to toggle the boot partition.

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

type 'a' to toggle the bootable flag

Comment: failed to read image. and replicates error:22

Answer (score 0):

`sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

```
Command (m for help): m
   Command action
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit bsd disklabel
   c   toggle the DOS compatibility flag
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   m   print this menu
   n   add a new partition
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   p   print the partition table
   q   quit without saving changes
   s   create a new empty Sun disklabel
   t   change a partition's system id
   u   change display/entry units
   v   verify the partition table
   w   write table to disk and exit
   x   extra functionality (experts only)
```